# Justified Gallery not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am unclear as to why the justified gallery I have setup here is not working.  It just seems to tile on top of the other images.

http://www.tamarackhomes.com/2017-touch/gallery.php?commID=7

http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/

```
$(".home-photos-container").justifiedGallery({
    rowHeight : 300,
    lastRow : 'nojustify',
    margins : 5
});

<div class="lay-rgt-con-hs">
        <div class="home-gallyer-container">
            <div class="home-photos-container">
                 <a href="/_gallery/1080/387923_Tamarack_FC_12 10 15_Hudson_007.jpg" class="photoBox" rel="photoGroup"><img src="/_gallery/640/387923_Tamarack_FC_12 10 15_Hudson_007.jpg" /></a>
                 <a href="/_gallery/1080/387923_Tamarack_FC_12 10 15_Hudson_007.jpg" class="photoBox" rel="photoGroup"><img src="/_gallery/640/387923_Tamarack_FC_12 10 15_Hudson_007.jpg" /></a>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what version of justifed gallery and jquery are you using ?

Comment: jquery 1.11 and justified gallery v3.6.0

Comment: have you tried updating to 3.6.3 ?

Comment: I've upgraded to 3.1.1 which is the latest stable build according to code.jquery.com.  This made no difference.  I do have this same gallery setup running elsewhere with 1.11 and it works.

Comment: I meant updating justified gallery not jquery(but that was a good try anyway)